# Responsive List Creates new column

Tags: html, list, css

I'm making a website that consist of a bunch of different sized lists. Some have 7 bullet points others have almost 20. I'm trying to create a css class where once I reach 5 bullet points on the 6th "li" it creates a new column.

I have something like this so far, but the problem with this is that I need to define the number of columns. How can I make it so that it would just start a new column on its own? Also it has to be a responsive!

Thank you

Code Below along with the jsfiddle

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>



ul {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

JsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/pdExf/467/

Comment: You want to break to new column after every 5 `li`?

Answer (score 1):

If you give the `ul` a `column-width` rather than a `column-count` then it behaves like you want. Also set the height, so that it can't grow higher than 6 lines.

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-width: 7em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-width: 7em;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-width: 7em;
  column-gap: 20px;
  column-fill: auto;
  line-height:1.2;
  height: 6em;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="listcontainer">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
    <li>Item 16</li>
    <li>Item 17</li>
    <li>Item 18</li>
    <li>Item 19</li>
    <li>Item 20</li>
    <li>Item 21</li>
    <li>Item 22</li>
    <li>Item 23</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you want a height of 6em..if there are to be 5 `li` per column.

Comment: That's indeed what the OP said in their question, but there were 6 `li`s per column in the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, but that was because he didn't know how to limit it to 5 

Comment: It looks fine to me (on my tablet) but there is no other way that I can think of.

Comment: It needed `column-fill:auto` in Mozilla. I've edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps flexbox offers a solution (somewhat similar to Mr Lister's solution it also requires a fixed height equal to the height of 5 `li`).

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KVgWyB)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #c0ffee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works perfect! Instead of having bullets I'm using font awesome with Mr. Lister solution for some reason the icons wouldn't load. With yours it does! However, is there a way to make it responsive?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by responsive...I've added a link to a Codepen demo..with font-awesome :)

Comment: Thank you! Yea I had that part working, but for example on your Codepen if I were to resize the browser it will stay as 4 columns how do I make it so it auto resizes and to like 2 columns then 1 column as the screen gets smaller

Comment: But you wanted 5 items per column...is that not a requirement any more?

Comment: @VinceMamba If you mean you want a minimum of 5 lines per column on wide screens, but more lines per column on narrower screens that can't fit as many columns, you should have said so in the question.